Excel file content shows gibberish letters instead of Hebrew
I exported data from a software to an Excel file but I get strange letters.
I tried to do ENCODING to UTF-8, open the file as CSV, NOTPAD++ and edit there but without success.
I also tried to open an empty Excel file and import data through the file and change the format there, but that didn't work either.
It seems I've tried almost everything and I'm already discouraged.
Example:


That really needs more info, if you have tried everything to import it without any success, the issue must be with the input file.

What software does your data reside in?

Just to make sure, when you import the file with File > Import > CSV, selecting the file and then for "File Origin" tried selecting Hebrew (DOS), (Windows), (Macintosh) and Unicode and none interprets the data correctly? Also, when you open the file in Notepad++, what is shown as the file type in the status bar?

@bugdrown It's internal software of the company i work for.

@nkalvi Indeed i did it.
In the notpad++ it shows me as excel file and ANSI in encoding.

Thanks @RaananHeinberg, so choosing Origin Type as 'Windows (ANSI)' produced gibberish. Could you please post a small sample of the original input along with the gibberish conversion?

@RaananHeinberg, also under Windows, there are few more variants, such as IBM (Hebrew), Logical and Visual etc. You may want to try with those as well.

Open a new workbook. Select Data-->Get & Transform Data-->From Text/CSV. Navigate to the file and select Open. At the bottom of the next window, select Load and in the next window select Table and Existing Worksheet ($A$1) and press Ok. Of course, there is a lot more to it but it's a start. Let us know if that works for you.

Hi @VBasic2008 , thanks for your answer , I did it but it doesn’t work

I solved the issue by change the language encoding in region setting - administrative - change to Hebrew . Thank you all.
